# REACT: Blank Page on localhost3000

Tags: java, reactjs, npm, localhost

I'm having problems trying to run this application when I try the `npm start` command. It should be showing `<h1>GPT-3</h1>` on `localhost3000` on my browser as it does on the code above:

```
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```
App.js
import React from 'react'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>GPT-3</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Before starting this application, I tried the command `npx create react-app ./` to create the files needed, after that I used `npm install react-icons` and finally `npm start` but it's not working as I planned.

npm -v
9.7.2

node -v
v18.16.1

Windows 11 -v
22H2

Chrome -v
115.0.5790.102 (Compilação oficial) (64 bits)

this message appears when I run the command `npm start`:
[`npm start`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L48oR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a typo, but your question states `localhost3000` when the port and url should be `localhost:3000`

If you still see a blank page then check the console using developer tools.

Depending on which version of React you're using, you might also need to update the method in which you are rendering on the root element as this has changed in the latest version.

Before:

```js
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

After:

```js
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
<App />,
)
```